# How to conver my JSON to NSArray

Tags: ios, json, swift3, nsarray

I'm new to Swift, i started learning on the new Swift 3
I've this as NSArray

```
var arrayName: NSArray = NSArray()

arrayName = ["name 1","name 2","name 3","name 4","name 5"]
```

The tableview currently prints those items above.

I want to get JSON online from `http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/`

and append `name` items to be the content of my `NSArray arrayName`

Comment: If you use Swift 3, prefer Swift Types like Array (`[String]`), and not Foundation/Objective-C ones NSArray. `NSArray` is not mutable (you can't add/remove items). Else, can you do the fetch to the URL? because there are plenty of question about that (Alamofire, URLSession, etc.) and their respective answers.

Comment: @Larme i use URLSession, i'm modifying and existing project, the current project has the array fixed as an NSArray, and when i fech the json it returns as [String], so I can't append them to the array

Comment: why so downvote, what's wrong with my question? i'm still new to iOS and swift :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first get the json data in a shared url session. **Make sure to check for the success flag in the completion closure**. Once you've got the data you can deserialize it with the JSONSerialization class, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization. So now you have the json in an object. Now you can convert it to a dictionary. In the dictionary traverse into "contacts" with the dictionary["contacts"] syntax. Next, cast the new object as a [[String: AnyObject]] which means array of dictionaries. From there, you can loop through and get the name property. Note: instead of casting the object as [[String: AnyObject]] you could also cast it as! NSArray.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if it works :) @Alamri if you need a reference there's an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517657/parse-json-swift-3

Comment: i tried what you said and it gives an error `Value of type NSArray has no member 'append'`

Comment: Use an array instead... NSArrays are immutable.

Comment: maybe i should not use append? or is it the right use?

Comment: i used `self.arrayName= (name as! NSArray)` and that error disappeared, but still crash on NSAraay as null, because the Array is called before it fetches and parse the json

Comment: still crash on NSAraay as null, because the Array is called before it fetches and parse the json i guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147638/discussion-between-mihir-thanekar-and-alamri).